# Web Hosted Picture Reading in Sagemaker via facenet_pytorch?

Tags: python, python-requests

Long shot but I am stuck. Running this test code in Amazon Sagemaker with a Python3 kernel and the function doesn't recognize the web location of the image (media.ci.org). I can't find anything in the documentation from facenet_pytorch about this, anyone know if this is possible? I can do this in R, but much slower.

```
pip install facenet-pytorch
from facenet_pytorch import MTCNN, InceptionResnetV1

# If required, create a face detection pipeline using MTCNN:
mtcnn = MTCNN()

# Create an inception resnet (in eval mode):
resnet = InceptionResnetV1(pretrained='vggface2').eval()

from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("https://media.ci.org/w_150/v1609425653/ChildPhotos/Published/08704975_wctwrt.jpg")
```

---

FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 img = Image.open("https://media.ci.org/w_150/v1609425653/ChildPhotos/Published/08704975_wctwrt.jpg")

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in open(fp, mode, formats)
3090
3091     if filename:
-> 3092         fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
3093         exclusive_fp = True
3094

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'https://media.ci.org/w_150/v1609425653/ChildPhotos/Published/08704975_wctwrt.jpg'

Answer (score 0):

You should ideally use requests to download the image locally and then using PIL.Image to open something like this.

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO

response = requests.get(url)
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
```

Comment: For my use case, that is impractical as I will be scanning some 3.1M photos. Do you have experience with this package referencing an S3 bucket? Or using Python IO to read the image to Bytes and then have Image.Open() read the IO Stream?